# How to add the Gson dependency in Android Studio Hedgehog (version 2023.1.1 Canary 14)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I have installed the latest Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Canary 14 version and am facing a problem while adding the Gson library. The dependencies section now looks like this:

```
dependencies {

implementation(libs.core.ktx)
implementation(libs.appcompat)
implementation(libs.material)
implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

}
```

and after adding

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

gives me an error unresolved reference

Comment: It looks like all the dependencies are in a separate file. You need to find a file where they can lie and add a new dependency there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

﻿In dependencies add:

```
implementation(libs.gson)
```

and in Version Catalog under [versions] add:

```
gson = "2.10.1"
```